# std::cin input not the same as direct assign std::string variable

Tags: c++, string, iostream, cin

I have a curious problem if I assign the variable via `std::cin`, it's different than the direct variable assign. The Example I string is not the same as the Example II string.

I use a xor decrypt function to decrypt the ciphertext.
If the variable is assigned through `std::cin`, I get the correct output(Example1). But if i assign the variable directly with the ciphertext string, i will get a different output(Example2).

What is different between a assign with `std::cin` and a direct variable assign?

#### Example I: (std::cin)

```
std::string my_input;
std::cin >> my_input;
```

> **INPUT:** 89001c110704918484dcdcdc85df9b9d8a2310005c08dccad8d7cccec3df824555a6dfced8df0045550
>   **OUTPUT:** http://www.test.de/|was|geht|½½½½½½½½¯

#### Example II: (direct variable assign)

```
std::string my_input;
my_input = "89001c110704918484dcdcdc85df9b9d8a2310005c08dccad8d7cccec3df824555a6dfced8df0045550";
```

> **OUTPUT:** test■½½www.test═¯¯óµ"$&┌©½░½)¯■

If i only get one line, the output is the same like the direct variable assign. But why?

```
std::string my_input;
std::getline(std::cin, my_input);
```

> **INPUT:** 89001c110704918484dcdcdc85df9b9d8a2310005c08dccad8d7cccec3df824555a6dfced8df0045550
>   **OUTPUT:** test■½½www.test═¯¯óµ"$&┌©½░½)¯■

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what your question is?  We'd love to help, but right now it's not clear what you want us to help you with.

Comment: How do you decide that the outputs are not same? Show us the outputs in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess as to what the problem is. (The question needs more detail.)

Replace your Example I code with this instead:

```
std::string my_input;
std::getline(std::cin, my_input);
```

What happens now?

Comment: Yes this i've testet before. Is the same output like the direct assign. I know. But why will the variable be cutted in a direct assign? Or where comes the endline in the direct assign?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input string does not contain any whitespace (which would cause `std::cin >> my_input` to return before consuming the entire string), the result should be identical. Instead of comparing the result after decrypting the text, you may want to compare the two strings that contain the ciphertext, something like:

```
std::string direct_assign;
local = "89001c110704918484dcdcdc85df9b9d8a2310005c08dccad8d7cccec3df824555a6dfced8df0045550";

std::string input;
std::cin >> input;

std::cout << (direct_assign == input) << std::endl;
```

Assuming the resulting strings are equal, there is no reason they should behave differently when being decrypted (unless there is an error in the decrypt function or how it is being invoked).

Comment: Yes, it's the same. Thx, for the code sniped.
I think it's a problem with a included lib. 
In standalone mode, only with the en/decrypt methods all is fine.